# Differentiating between 0 and empty cell with VLOOKUP in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use VLOOKUP in [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECkBWE2zD-V6GZQhM4GAGQtrZ-b1z5pccJUkjCVFX84/edit#gid=2081903823) to convert percentage grades to a 1–8 grading scale. I would like to be able to differentiate between a score of 0 and an empty score but am having trouble making this work.

Here's the current formula I'm using:
`=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP((C2/$C$6),'Grade Boundaries'!$A$3:$B$10,2,true)),"",VLOOKUP((C2/$C$6),'Grade Boundaries'!$A$3:$B$10,2,true))`

**Current behavior**

The Adjusted column shows 1 whether the corresponding Raw value is 0 or blank.

**Desired behavior**

The Adjusted column should show 1 if the corresponding Raw value is 0, or N/A if the corresponding Raw value is blank.

I've tried looking at other suggestions here and using IF statements, but I seem to keep getting stuck with the fact that VLOOKUP doesn't appear to differentiate between a value of zero and an empty cell.

[Link to example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECkBWE2zD-V6GZQhM4GAGQtrZ-b1z5pccJUkjCVFX84/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is related to a larger issue, namely the equality of various "blank" or "zero" values when accessed by spreadsheet functions.

Most spreadsheet functions will consider truly blank values equal to zero-length text strings `""`. Conversely, many of them will consider truly blank values equal to zero, but zero-length text strings `""` *not* equal to zero. To add to the mix, some spreadsheet functions will not consider `""` blank, notably `isblank()` and `counta()`:

| value | how to get it | `=value=0` | `=value=""` | `=isblank(value)` | `=counta(value)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| truly blank value | `=iferror(1/0)` | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | 0 |
| zero-length string | `=""` | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | 1 |
| zero | `0` | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 1 |

One way to differentiate between truly blank values, zero-length text strings and zeros is to use a combination of `isblank()` and `to_text()` to get the value in the cell as a text string in the format it shows in the spreadsheet, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  isblank(C2), na(), 
  to_text(C2) = "0", 1, 
  C2 = "", iferror(1/0), 
  true, vlookup(C2 / $C$6, 'Grade Boundaries'!$A$3:$B$10, 2, true)
)
```

To make the formula easier to read, assign names with `let()`:

```
=let( 
  cell, C2, 
  percent, to_percent(cell / $C$6), 
  lookup, 'Grade Boundaries'!$A$3:$B$10, 
  ifs( 
    isblank(cell), na(), 
    to_text(cell) = "0", 1, 
    cell = "", iferror(1/0), 
    true, vlookup(percent, lookup, columns(lookup), true) 
  ) 
)
```

Note that `to_text()` gets the value in the cell as a text string *in the format it shows in the spreadsheet*. For example, if the values are formatted as **Format > Number > Number**, you need compare against `"0.00"`.

See [to_text()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285) and [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535).

Comment: Very helpful explanation and solution. Thank you!